# How to create a table of <div> elements and add an unknown amount of rows to it dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a  table that currently needs 30 rows, but computations could change that later on. I don't want to fill my html file with 30 div 'rows' so I tried creating one row and using an HTMLCollection to add to it. What's the best way to go about managing how large the HTMLCollection will become and inserting data into the table later on? Would learning jQuery be better for this?

```
arr = document.getElementsByClassName('table-row');
```

Having trouble appending child nodes 'table-row'.

Comment: No, you don't need jQuery for this.

Comment: Just use a loop? I'm not quite sure what the problem is. Maybe you could post the code that you currently have?

Comment: arr = document.getElementsByClassName('table-row');



something like that to get the HTMLCollection, then what method can I use to keep appending to it?

Comment: [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)?

Comment: @Jva47 No, you cannot just put more elements in that collection. You will need to [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) them to the table body, so that the elements know where they belong in the DOM tree.

Answer (score -1):

If you want an easy solution, you can just use `.innerHTML` and append more rows to the first row.

The code below basically adds `<div id="${i}">${i}</div>` to the last row.

```js
let num = 30;

for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
  document.getElementById(i - 1).innerHTML += 
  `
  <div id="${i}">${i}</div>
  `
}
```

```html
<div id="1">1</div>
```

Comment: Might be easy, but is really horrible from a performance and cleanliness point of view.